# DataGrid ToolTip - Show content

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a problem with ToolTip (dataGrid), it not showing content from each cell. Maybe I'm not binding to the right property (in this case ToolTip="{Binding ColumnProperty}")

```
 <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          MaxColumnWidth="200"
                          CanUserSortColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="4 2 2 2"
                          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="4 2 2 2"
                          ToolTip="{Binding ColumnProperty}"/>
```

Comment: What u want to achieve through tooltip?

Comment: I want for each cell to have ToolTip with text content. Because MaxColumnWidth is fixed at 200, sometimes in a cell the text not fit entirely

Comment: U can disable autogeneration of columns which will give you more control for customizing the cell. Then u can use cellstyle to set tool tip and other properties too. Check out [cellstyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What is `ColumnProperty`? If you want to display the contents of a particular cell in a tooltip, it's certainly not enough to just set a property of the `DataGrid` itself. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently setting the tooltip for the whole Datagrid. 
the different types of DataGridColumns may have their own tooltip property, or you can use an item template to set the tooltip for the actual text-elements themselves.

Comment: Thx David for your answer, I wanted to avoid cell template. Datagrid is biding directly to ObservableCollection, generating columns for each property.  I want for each cell to have ToolTip with text content. Because MaxColumnWidth is fixed at 200, sometimes in a cell the text not fit entirely